# Filter a long list in Powershell

Tags: powershell, filter

If you wanted to filter names that contain the first letter w and are followed by 'x' amount of numbers, then how do you filter it?

for example:

w34593
w44569a
we5552
w01123
w85532

I've been starting off with

```
$userIDs = Get-Aduser -filter {name -like "w3*" -or name -like "w4*"} -Properties * | Select name, SurName, DisplayName
```

Issue is some get long where they start with w1, w2, w3, w0 and I don't want to filter each one or the code with be stupidly long.

any suggestions? Each name is usually 6 to 7 characters long so is there a range length that could help me? i tried .length but it doesn't seem to work for my version of powershell

Update:

```
$userIDs = Get-Aduser -filter {(name -gt "w30000*" -and name -lt "w99999*") -or (name -gt "we0000*" -and name -lt "we9999*") `
         -or (name -gt "cr0000*" -and name -lt "cr9999*") -or (name -gt "ac0000**" -and name -lt "ac9999*")`
         -or (name -gt "cm0000*" -and name -lt "cm9999*") -or (name -gt "do0000*" -and name -lt "do9999*") `
         -or (name -gt "ec0000*" -and name -lt "ec9999*") -or (name -gt "ev0000*" -and name -lt "ev9999*") `
         -or (name -gt "fm0000*" -and name -lt "fm9999*") -or (name -gt "ia0000*" -and name -lt "ia9999*") `
         -or (name -gt "in0000*" -and name -lt "in9999*") -or (name -gt "le0000*" -and name -lt "le9999*") `
         -or (name -gt "md0000*" -and name -lt "md9999*") -or (name -gt "mk0000*" -and name -lt "mk9999*") `
         -or (name -gt "np0000*" -and name -lt "np9999*") -or (name -gt "pb0000*" -and name -lt "pb9999*") `
         -or (name -gt "ps0000*" -and name -lt "ps9999*") -or (name -gt "re0000*" -and name -lt "re9999*") `
         -or (name -gt "sf0000*" -and name -lt "sf9999*") -or (name -gt "so0000*" -and name -lt "so9999*") `
         -or (name -gt "tr0000*" -and name -lt "tr9999*") -or (name -gt "wn0000*" -and name -lt "wn9999*") } `
         -Properties * | Select name, SurName, DisplayName, enabled
```

ERROR:

```
Get-ADUser : Error parsing query: '(name -gt "w30000*" -and name -lt "w99999*")
-or (name -gt "we0000*" -and name -lt "we9999*") `
         -or (name -gt "cr0000*" -and name -lt "cr9999*") -or (name -gt "ac
0000**" -and name -lt "ac9999*")`
         -or (name -gt "cm0000*" -and name -lt "cm9999*") -or (name -gt "do
0000*" -and name -lt "do9999*") `
         -or (name -gt "ec0000*" -and name -lt "ec9999*") -or (name -gt "ev
0000*" -and name -lt "ev9999*") `
         -or (name -gt "fm0000*" -and name -lt "fm9999*") -or (name -gt "ia
0000*" -and name -lt "ia9999*") `
         -or (name -gt "in0000*" -and name -lt "in9999*") -or (name -gt "le
0000*" -and name -lt "le9999*") `
         -or (name -gt "md0000*" -and name -lt "md9999*") -or (name -gt "mk
0000*" -and name -lt "mk9999*") `
         -or (name -gt "np0000*" -and name -lt "np9999*") -or (name -gt "pb
0000*" -and name -lt "pb9999*") `
         -or (name -gt "ps0000*" -and name -lt "ps9999*") -or (name -gt "re
0000*" -and name -lt "re9999*") `
         -or (name -gt "sf0000*" -and name -lt "sf9999*") -or (name -gt "so
0000*" -and name -lt "so9999*") `
         -or (name -gt "tr0000*" -and name -lt "tr9999*") -or (name -gt "wn
0000*" -and name -lt "wn9999*") ' Error Message: 'Operator Not supported: ' at 
position: '95'.
At J:\DATA\IR\ITSecurity\Intern\AlyssaC 2014\Part-time 2014-2015 task\AD\AD cle
an-up\Daily Script\AD-User.MonitorOwnership.ps1:3 char:22
+ $userIDs = Get-Aduser <<<<  -filter {(name -gt "w30000*" -and name -lt "w9999
9*") -or (name -gt "we0000*" -and name -lt "we9999*") `
   + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [Get-ADUser], ADFilterParsingEx 
   ception
 + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Error parsing query: '(name -gt "w30000*" -and n 
 ame -lt "w99999*") -or (name -gt "we0000*" -and name -lt "we9999*") `
             -or (name -gt "cr0000*" -and name -lt "cr9999*") -or (name -g 
t "ac0000**" -and name -lt "ac9999*")`
             -or (name -gt "cm0000*" -and name -lt "cm9999*") -or (name -g 
t "do0000*" -and name -lt "do9999*") `
             -or (name -gt "ec0000*" -and name -lt "ec9999*") -or (name -g 
t "ev0000*" -and name -lt "ev9999*") `
             -or (name -gt "fm0000*" -and name -lt "fm9999*") -or (name -g 
t "ia0000*" -and name -lt "ia9999*") `
             -or (name -gt "in0000*" -and name -lt "in9999*") -or (name -g 
t "le0000*" -and name -lt "le9999*") `
              -or (name -gt "md0000*" -and name -lt "md9999*") -or (name -g 
t "mk0000*" -and name -lt "mk9999*") `
             -or (name -gt "np0000*" -and name -lt "np9999*") -or (name -g 
t "pb0000*" -and name -lt "pb9999*") `
             -or (name -gt "ps0000*" -and name -lt "ps9999*") -or (name -g 
t "re0000*" -and name -lt "re9999*") `
             -or (name -gt "sf0000*" -and name -lt "sf9999*") -or (name -g 
 t "so0000*" -and name -lt "so9999*") `
             -or (name -gt "tr0000*" -and name -lt "tr9999*") -or (name -g 
 t "wn0000*" -and name -lt "wn9999*") ' Error Message: 'Operator Not suppor  
ted: ' at position: '95'.,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.Ge   
 tADUser
```

UPDATE 2: this time i did each one individually and they worked???? I don't understand why my main filter doesn't work unless they are filtered individually

Some of them:

```
$wIDs = Get-Aduser -filter {(name -gt "w30000*" -and name -lt "w99999*")} -Properties * | Select name, SurName, DisplayName, enabled
$weIDs = Get-Aduser -filter {(name -gt "we0000*" -and name -lt "we9999*")} -Properties * | Select name, SurName, DisplayName, enabled

foreach ($user in $wIDs) {

if ($user.DisplayName -like "*-DISABLED"){

#$groups = get-Adgroup -properties managedby -filter {managedby -eq $user.name}

write-host "User ID: " $user.name
write-host "Last Name: " $user.SurName
write-host "Display Name: " $user.DisplayName

write-host $break1 "Next User:" $break1
}#end of if statement

}#end foreach

foreach ($user in $weIDs) {

if ($user.DisplayName -like "*-DISABLED"){

#$groups = get-Adgroup -properties managedby -filter {managedby -eq $user.name}

write-host "User ID: " $user.name
write-host "Last Name: " $user.SurName
write-host "Display Name: " $user.DisplayName
#write-host "Managed Groups: " $groups

write-host $break1 "Next User:" $break1
}#end of if statement

}#end foreach
```

These print correctly with no errors????

Comment: The w IDs work but the rest dont. I get this huge error

Comment: I removed the * and the error is still there... i will show my update again: this time I filtered each one individually (very bad cuz my script is very long but all of them work if I do it individually so something in my main filter is wrong)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The use of `-Filter` is preferred for performance reasons since `Get-ADUser` wont be returning all user objects. However, in this case, I think because of the amount of conditional criteria that a regex based after the fact might be a better fit for this. So unless you have 10's of 1000's of users this should work just fine. Also you are returing *all* user properties but then only taking 4. That would be a performance hit in itself. The only thing that is not default is `Enabled` so we will be sure to take that.

```
$prefixes = "cr","cm","ec","fm","in","md","np","ps","sf","tr","ac","do","ev","ia","le","mk","pb","re","so","wn","we","w[3-9]"
$regex = "^($($prefixes -Join "|"))\d*"
$results = Get-ADUser -Filter * -Properties Enabled,DisplayName | 
    Where-Object{$_.Name -match $regex} | 
    Select Name,SurName,DisplayName,Enabled
$results
```

Basically building a regex match string where the name must start with one of the groups of two characters* (the w30000 criteria is different than the other so that is why at the end you see `w[3-9]` which mean "w" followed by a number that is "3 to 9") which is followed by some numbers. The string is built from the array of  `$prefixes` that you can add and remove as you please.

This might not fit your exact criteria but it can be changed easily depending on what it is matching. Pretty sure as well that `-lt`,`-gt`,etc does not support wildcards. Think it treats them as the literal asterisks character. `-like` and `-notlike` support wildcards.

Are there account that exist with different 2 character prefixes? If not this could be done with a much simple regex like `^\w{2}\d+` which is 2 characters followed by at least one digit.

Comment: I thank you for such detail and explanation. I have never seen the \d+ code before. I tried printing your example to get a feel of how it worked but nothing happened. I also think the prefixes variable wouldn't work for me given there are also other ids that start with cr..cm and etc but have no numbers. hmm...

Comment: I changed the `+` to a `*` so it would match "cm" and "ec0000". Can you show me an example of other names that would match? also are these actual names or samaccountnames? @AlyssaCooke

Comment: for fm: fmsad. for in: install99, install... . for ev: evaltes... and etc. These are actual names too

Comment: After changing the digits to optional (which was not mentioned in your question btw) and running a test on my own organization this was working for me.. also i had my brackets wrong @AlyssaCooke. Copy my updated code and let me know

Comment: Ok yes your's does work. I see what you did with the brackets now. Your example is much easier to understand. I appreciate it. I will play with your example and see where I can go from here. Thank you very much for explaining a lot.

Comment: @AlyssaCooke. Assuming mjolinor's answer fits your criteria it has the ease of mine with the performance mine lacks.

Comment: I accidentally added 2 points to the post below this one. Not sure how to fix it. I am also not sure what you mean performance your's lacks?

Comment: You didnt add two points. I added a point and you a point as well. If you have large amount of users the other answer here would perform faster than mine.

Answer (score 2):

Does this work for you?

```
Get-Aduser -filter {name -gt "w3000" -and name -lt "w9999"}
```

Edit:

Given new requirements:

```
$prefixes = "cr","cm","ec","fm","in","md","np","ps","sf","tr","ac","do","ev","ia","le","mk","pb","re","so","wn","we"

#Create filter for searches
$DNFilters = $prefixes -replace '^','(Name=' -replace '$','*)'
$Filter = "(|$DNFilters)"


Get-ADUser -LDAPFilter $Filter -Properties Enabled |
 Where-Object {$_.name -like '??[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'}
```

That will let you use early filtering to return just the accounts with names that match the prefixes.  The late filter `(Where-Object)` will then filter the ones that don't have 4 digits following.

Edit:
This line:

```
$DNFilters = $prefixes -replace '^','(Name=' -replace '$','*)'
```

Takes each prefix, and pre-pends the string `'(Name='` and then appends the string `'*)'` to it.  The result is, for e.g. the prefix 'cr' will become `'(Name=cr*)'` .  That is the LDAP filter for any name that starts with 'cr'.

Then this line:

```
$Filter = "(|$DNFilters)"
```

wraps those in '(|' and ')' . The '|' in an LDAP filter means 'OR'.  The resulting filter looks like this:

```
(|(Name=cr*) (Name=cm*) (Name=ec*) (Name=fm*) (Name=in*) (Name=md*) (Name=np*) (Name=ps*) (Name=sf*) (Name=tr*) (Name=ac*) (Name=do*) (Name=ev*) (Name=ia*) (Name=le*) (Name=mk*) (Name=pb*) (Name=re*) (Name=so*) (Name=wn*) (Name=we*))
```

All of the individual LDAP filters are ORed together into one filter.

In this line:

```
Where-Object {$_.name -like '??[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'}
```

the `??` means "any two characters".  In wildcard match (`-like`) the `?` means "any single character".

Comment: it runs extremely slow that I tend to have to restart it :/ wow

Comment: ok i accidently didn't change to -and and had -le instead of -lt. It works.. thanks!!!

Comment: An error came up. I think its because of the w since gt and lt are for numbers only

Comment: If you look at http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847759.aspx @AlyssaCooke you will see that it is for strings and numbers. It all depends on what is on the left hand side.

Comment: You may not be able to get exactly what you're after using an LDAP filter, but you can use that to prune the results down so that you have very little left to filter out using late filtering.

Comment: Never occurred to me to make a better LDAP filter. Good work.

Comment: Can you explain what these 2 lines do:
$DNFilters = $prefixes -replace '^','(Name=' -replace '$','*)'
$Filter = "(|$DNFilters)"

Also, what the 2 '??' mean on the last code

Comment: Added some comments to the answer.

Comment: ok mjolinor thank you very much for all the explanation. I wanted to make sure I fully understood your process.

Comment: You're welcome.  The regex solution should work too, but I suspect this will be much more efficient.